# How to create tabs inside a tab using clarity design

Tags: vmware-clarity

Previously I was using `TabLink` component of clarity-angular to create tabs. Now, after i upgraded to `@clr/angular` i'm not able to use `TabLink` so i'm unable to create tabs inside a tab. How do I proceed?

Comment: Have you reviewed https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/tabs? If not, please share some sample code to demonstrate your approach.

Answer (score 5):

This should work, I just copied our example code [in the docs](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/tabs) for the **Simple Tabs** example and nested it inside of tab 2. See this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nested-clarity-tabs) for functional code.

```
        <clr-tabs>
          <clr-tab>
              <button clrTabLink id="link1">Tab1</button>
              <clr-tab-content id="content1" *clrIfActive>
              tab 1
              </clr-tab-content>
          </clr-tab>
          <clr-tab>
              <button clrTabLink>Tab2</button>
              <clr-tab-content *clrIfActive="true">
              tab2
                <clr-tabs>
                  <clr-tab>
                      <button clrTabLink id="link1">Tab1</button>
                      <clr-tab-content id="content1" *clrIfActive>
                      tab 2.1
                      </clr-tab-content>
                  </clr-tab>
                  <clr-tab>
                      <button clrTabLink>Tab2</button>
                      <clr-tab-content *clrIfActive="true">
                      tab 2.2
                      </clr-tab-content>
                  </clr-tab>
              </clr-tabs>
              </clr-tab-content>
          </clr-tab>
      </clr-tabs>
```